# Is there a way to hang mini blinds with only 1/2" of space to mount the brackets?

Tags: windows, hanging, brackets, blinds, mount

I had all of the windows in my house replaced last week and I just assumed that my fairly new mini blinds would be able to be put back up but once the new windows were in, but there is now only a little over a 1/2" of space left to hang brackets and the 2" brackets I had up before will not fit at all. I need them to be mounted on the inside so that the wood around my windows isn't covered up, so outside mounting is not an option for me and it's definitely not in my budget to get custom blinds made right now so I am at a loss as to what to do now. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I've mounted blinds in similar situations. A photo would be very helpful, though. I'm reluctant to offer suggestions in the blind. So to speak.